# Error when installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've tried to google for it but I couldn't find a solution.
I have Windows on my disk and I'm trying to install Ubuntu with dualboot but when I install ubuntu on SSD or HDD I get this error:

```
The creation of swap space in partition #1 of Encrypted volume0
(cryptswap1) failed
```

I choose install Ubuntu alongside Windows and than I could use the default option with my HDD and an option to create a new partition on my SSD – both fails.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please be more detailed: what steps did you try, what went wrong, what succeeded.

Comment: @Danatela updated it, hope its enough.

Comment: Try to make partition from Windows, then install into that partition through _Custom Setup_. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/343370/171636) is the manual on how to do it.

Comment: i don't know exactly what i did but i reduce my disk and left some free space and i could install ubuntu on that